# SQL-Server/Access - Order BY 1,2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I came across a query today,

```
SELECT col1,'yes' as col2  FROM myTable  
   WHERE col2=TRUE  
UNION  
SELECT col1,'no' as col2 FROM mytable  
   WHERE col2=FALSE  
ORDER BY 1,2
```

I thought it would order by first column and then second but since a UNION is involved I am a bit unsure can someone explain the exact meaning of this query

Comment: Did you mean to include Access for a reason? Which RDBMS are you executing the query against?

Comment: Well, apart from your question, I have one of my own, why are you doing it like this? Surely a `SELECT col1, CASE WHEN col2 = TRUE THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END as col2 FROM mytable ORDER BY 1, 2` would be preferable, no?

Comment: @Lasse: Generally speaking, the query you are suggesting is not entirely equivalent to the OP's. If `col2` is nullable and does contain NULLs, the two queries, yours and OP's, would return different results. But basically you've made an excellent point, of course.

Comment: @Andriy Agreed, I did not consider NULL's at all, that would have to be taken into account in such a solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SQL Server will union the results together (which is an implied select distinct) and then order the results by col1 then col2.  In a union query, you can put an ORDER BY on the final select, which will sort the final result.